# How to find common properties between the nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm having few nodes, let's say n1,n2....etc,

```
      N1 : {role:"admin",lang:"english",location:"Hyd"}     

      N2  : {role:"admin",lang:"hindi",location:"Hyd"}
```

how to list common properties between the nodes N1 and N2, here it will be role and location.

Comment: Hi Pavan can you add some more detail of what you are trying to achieve. Do you just want to list known properties between two nodes or are you trying to describe the set of similarities between N objects without being specific about the properties to compare?

Comment: Why not having separate nodes for role, lang and location, in order to leverage the power of the graph ?

Comment: Hi John, i just wanted to describe the set of similarities between N objects without being specific about the properties to compare

Comment: Hi Christophe Willemsen, I'm new to Neo4J. please give me a brief on choosing how to decide node/property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cypher language has no facilities for schema introspection (that is, the discovery of all the properties of a node or relationship).

However, the [REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api.html) does. See, for example, the [`Get properties for node`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-node-properties.html#rest-api-get-properties-for-node) API.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Will help you

```
MATCH (N1:node),(N2:node)
WHERE N1.role = "admin" AND N2.role = "admin"
CREATE (N1)-[r:COMMONROLE]->(N2)
RETURN r
```